# What filter should I use to get a good number of upvoted answers and those are new?

Tags: support, search

I was said to use the search bar to see how upvoted questions look like and that too new ones. I saw the filter and if I filter by votes, I get 11-year-old posts and if I filter for newest I get 0 votes posts.

I have zero or less votes for all Stack Overflow posts. I need to see new posts that have a good number of upvotes.

Comment: I typed "python" for what I got 11years old questions.

Comment: Here are the extra search params: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching

Comment: Thanks @rene , I didn't have idea that SO also uses filters like GitHub.

Comment: [try this one](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+created%3A1y+score%3A2+isaccepted%3A1&mixed=0)

Comment: Thanks for the example @rene. It would have definitely taken more time for me to understand the syntax of searching otherwise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the 0 to any number you like, so if you want to set a lower bound of 10, raise it to 10.

So, the query would be `is:q score:10 [tag1]` if you wanted to see the questions with a score of 10 or more in a specific tag. To find the most recent, change the sort to "Newest" as you already figured out. If you are interested in high-scoring answers, you can use `is:a` instead of `is:q`.

Some of these helpful search terms are listed at the top of the page when you click in the search bar:

[image: Screenshot of the search dropdown help pane showing some examples of common search terms]

And the full list of search functions can be seen on the [advanced search help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching) by clicking "Search help" in the pane's lower right corner.

Comment: the question title is about *answers* so an `is:a` might be relevant as well ...

Comment: .... meh. I'd originally excluded the is:q but, yeah. ... odd, that isn't one of the examples shown in the helper menu.

Comment: It would be awesome if we could have a link that opens the search page with the *advanced search tips* expanded ... the few tricks I tried all failed miserably

Comment: Oh, that'd be cool.

Comment: Give it 6 to 8 weeks .. ;)